# Remove rows that are assoicated to certain columns value

Tags: r

I am new to R, I have 0's and 1's X matrix and associated with y's as the data.
I need to remove the observations that have less than 10 one's so I add the columns for x and i return the column name to a vector. then drop the y's that associated with the one's then I need to remove the columns because it will be column with zero.
so I am getting this error and I dont know how to fix and improve the code 
Error in -Col[i] : invalid argument to unary operator

Here is the code

```
a0=rep(1,40)
a=rep(0:1,20)
b=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))
c0=c(rep(0,12),rep(1,28))
c1=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,35))
c2=c(rep(1,8),rep(0,32))
c3=c(rep(1,23),rep(0,17))
x=matrix(cbind(a0,a,b,c0,c1,c2,c3),nrow=40,ncol=7)
nam <- paste("V",1:7,sep="")
colnames(x)<-nam
dat <- cbind(y=rnorm(40,50,7),x)
#===================================
toSum <- apply(dat,2,sum)
Col <- Val <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(toSum)){
if(toSum[i]<10){
Col <- c(Col,colnames(dat)[i])
Val <- c(Val,toSum[i])}
}

for(i in 1:length(Col)){
indx <- dat[,Col[i]]==0
datnw <- dat[indx,]
datnw2 <- datnw[,-Col[i]]
}
```

Can some one help please? I am not sure if there is a way to get the position for the columns in Col vector. I have around 1500 columns on my original data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
   datnw2 <- dat[, -which(toSum<10)]
```

This allows you to avoid the loop

```
 head(datnw2)
            y V1 V2 V3 V4 V7
[1,] 60.88166  1  0  1  0  1
[2,] 54.35388  1  1  1  0  1
[3,] 39.78881  1  0  1  0  1
[4,] 44.20074  1  1  1  0  1
[5,] 42.27351  1  0  1  0  1
[6,] 43.52390  1  1  1  0  1
```

**Edit**: Some pointers

`toSum<10` will give a logical vector to you, the length of this vector is the same as `length(toSum)`
`which(toSum<10)` will give you the positions of those elements meeting the condition

Since you want to select those columns from `dat` which the associated `toSum<10` is `FALSE`, then you have to left those columns out by doing `dat[, -which(toSum<10)]`, this means: chose all columns but 6 and 7 which are the ones meeting condition `toSum<10`

Comment: thank you for the explanation. can you please tell me why this code is not working and how I make it work                   cs <- colSums(dat) < 10
indx<-dat[,which(cs)]==0
datnw<-dat[indx,]
#now need to remove columns of X
datnw2 <- datnw[,-which(cs)]

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data, if you want to find which rows (i.e. observations) have fewer than 10 `1`s

```
rs <- rowSums(dat[, -1]) < 10
```

If you want to know which columns (i.e. variables) have less than 10 "presences" then

```
cs <- colSums(dat[, -1]) < 10

R> cs
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Both `rs` and `cs` are logical variables that can be used to index to remove rows/columns.

To get rid of the columns we use:

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2 <- dat2[, !cs]
head(dat2)

R> head(dat2)
            y V1 V2 V3 V6 V7
[1,] 47.61253  1  0  1  1  1
[2,] 60.51697  1  1  1  1  1
[3,] 53.69815  1  0  1  1  1
[4,] 53.79534  1  1  1  1  1
[5,] 49.04329  1  0  1  1  1
[6,] 42.04286  1  1  1  1  1
```

Next it seems that you are concerned that some rows will now be all zero? Is that what you are trying to do with the final step? That doesn't appear to be the case here, so perhaps the way or removing the columns I show has solved that problem too?

```
R> rowSums(dat2[,-1])
 [1] 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 2 3 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
[39] 1 2
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is the following remove the rows of 1's if the sum of the column less than 10. In my example if you add the columns you can see that V5 and V6 < 10. so I want to remove the first 8 rows first,then remove the columns because they are zero columns now.Hope this explain what I am trying to do